# How to append current lines to previous line when its start with 'id'

Tags: python

My Problem is the following

I have one text file, it contains more than 1000 rows, want to read files line by line
I am trying this code, but not getting expected output

my source file:

```
uuid;UserGroup;Name;Description;Owner;Visibility;Members  ----> header of the file
id:;group1;raji;xyzabc;ramya;public;
abc
def
geh

id:group2;raji;rtyui;ramya;private
cvb
nmh
poi
```

```
import csv
output=[]
temp=[]
fo = open ('usergroups.csv', 'r')
for line in fo:
    #next(uuid)
    line = line.strip() 
    if not line:
        continue #ignore empty lines
        #temp.append(line)
    if not line.startswith('id:') and not None:
        temp.append(line)
        print(line)
    else:
        if temp: 
           line += ";" + ",".join(temp)
           temp.clear() 
        output.append(line)
print("\n".join(output))
with open('new.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(output)
```

i am getting this output:
id;group1;raji;xyzabc;ramya;public;uuid;UserGroup;Name;Description;Owner;Visibility;Members
id:group2;raji;rtyui;ramya;private;abc,def,geh

So whenever a line does not start with 'id' it should be appended to the previous line.

my desired output:

```
uuid;UserGroup;Name;Description;Owner;Visibility;Members  ----> header of the file
id;group1;raji;xyzabc;ramya;public;abc,def,geh
id:group2;raji;rtyui;ramya;private;cvb,nmh,poi
```

Comment: How does your current code fail?

Comment: if not line.startswith('id:') and not None: #the and not None does not actually do anything here as far as I know

Comment: @SiHa heading appended to 1st line and abc,def,geh appended to below line of the file and cvb,nmh,poi does not appended to any line, this is the issue

Comment: Plus, in "line.startswith('id:')" you are checking for a ":", whereas in your textfile, one of the line has a ";" instead of that.

Comment: @SiHa updated output of the code and line start with 'id:'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to a file has not been included here, but there is a list of strings available to work with, as in your original code.
Note: this is not really an answer to your question, as it is a solution to your problem

The structure is by and large the same, with a few changes for readability.
Readable code is easier to get right

```
import csv

output = []
temp = []
currIdLine = ""
with( open ('usergroups.csv', 'r')) as f:
    for dirtyline in f.readlines():
        line = dirtyline.strip()
        if not line:
            print("Skipping empty line")
            continue

        if line.startswith('uuid'): # append the header to the output
            output.append(line)
            continue

        if line.startswith('id'):
            if temp:
                print(temp)
                output.append(currIdLine + ";" + ','.join(temp)) #based on current input, there is a bug here where the output will contain two sequential ';' characters
                temp.clear()
            currIdLine = line
        else:
            temp.append(line)
output.append(currIdLine + ";" + ','.join(temp))

print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! ,in your code  all lines are merged as a single line

Comment: like this ['uuid;UserGroup;Name;Description;Owner;Visibility;Members','id;group1;raji;xyzabc;ramya;public;abc,def,geh','id:group2;raji;rtyui;ramya;private;cvb,nmh,poi']

Comment: so i have added    print("\n".join(output)) instead of print(output), Thanks for your effort, much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

There are a few mistakes. I'll only show the relevant corrections:

Use

```
    if not line.startswith('id'):
```

No `'id:'`, since you also have a line starting with `'id;'`, plus you state yourself that a line has to start with "id" (no ":" there). The `and if None` part is unneccessary, because it's always true.

The other part:

```
        output.append(line.split(';'))
```

because `writerows` need an iterable (list) of "row" objects, and a row object is a list of string. So you need a list of lists, which the above is, thanks to the extra split.
(Of course, now the line `print("\n".join(output))` fails, but `writer.writerows(output)` works.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will help you but with regex, this problem is solved in a very simple way. I leave here the code in case you are interested.

```py
import regex as re

input_text = """uuid;UserGroup;Name;Description;Owner;Visibility;Members  ----> header of the file
id;group1;raji;xyzabc;ramya;public;
abc
def
geh

id:group2;raji;rtyui;ramya;private
cvb
nmh
poi"""

formatted = re.sub(r"\n(?!(id|\n))", "", input_text)

print(formatted)
```

```bash
uuid;UserGroup;Name;Description;Owner;Visibility;Members  ----> header of the file
id;group1;raji;xyzabc;ramya;public;abcdefgeh

id:group2;raji;rtyui;ramya;privatecvbnmhpoi
```

This code just replace the regular expression `\n(?!(id|id|n))` with the empty string.  This regular expression will replace all line breaks that are not followed by the word "id" or another line break (so we keep the space between the two lines of ids).

Comment: unnecessary complex way of solving the issue I think. regex isn't a silver bullet. it's more of a glass canon

Comment: Of course, regular expressions are not the solution to all problems. In fact, there are quite a few cases where, as you say, they become a difficult thing to manage. However, their usefulness in solving certain types of problems and regex should not be underestimated. In this case, the regex is simple and easy to create, I don't see any problem in using it.